# How to send USDT TRC20 via Python

Tags: python, tronpy

How can I send USDT TRC20 via Python?

I used this code:

```
from tronpy import Tron
from tronpy.keys import PrivateKey

client = Tron(network='mainnet')
priv_key = PrivateKey(bytes.fromhex("0"))

txn = (
    client.trx.transfer(from_="0", to="0", amount=1_000)
    .memo("0")
    .build()
    .sign(priv_key)
)
print(txn.txid)
print(txn.broadcast().wait())
```

But it did not send usdt, but instead trx.

A network change does not help.

Comment: What is USDT? [The ticker symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USDT) for the [Tether](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tether_(cryptocurrency)) stablecoin cryptocurrency?

Comment: Re *"it did not send usdt, but instead trx."*: Literally "usdt" and "trx"?

Comment: [TRX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tron_(cryptocurrency)): *"...a cryptocurrency native to the system, known as Tronix (TRX)"*

Answer (score 0):

```
contract = tron.get_contract('TR7NHqjeKQxGTCi8q8ZY4pL8otSzgjLj6t')
tx = (
         contract.functions.transfer(address_to, amount)
         .with_owner(your_address)
         .fee_limit(your fee)
         .build()
         .sign(PrivateKey(bytes.fromhex(your pk))))
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: As suggested before, please consider adding an explanation of how your code attempts to answer the question.